# the greatest number in the property "basename" of my list of directories

Tags: powershell

I want to have the  greatest number in the property "basename"  of my list of directories.
I don't understand why it doesn't work.
I have 21 directories from the number 1 to 21 in my directory D:\Coala\global\patch
for my program the max is 9 whereas The max  for me is 21

$max and $item.BaseName have the type "int" in he loop "foreach"

What is the solution please?

```
 Here is my code:

$path0="D:\Coala\global\patch\"   
    $Updates0 = Get-ChildItem -path $path0  


foreach ($item in $Updates0) {
  
  [int]$max=0
  [int]$item.BaseName
  if ($item.BaseName -gt $max) {
   
    $max=$item.BaseName
    
}
}
write-host the max is $max


The output of my code is:
  PS D:\powershell> d:\powershell\shell1.ps1

1
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
2
20
21
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
the max is 9
```

Comment: `if ($item.BaseName -gt $max) {` -> `if ([int]$item.BaseName -gt $max) {`

Comment: even if  I do this, the my max of my code is always the number 9

Comment: Also do `$max=[int]$item.BaseName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this result is that the `Basename` property is a *string* - and when we sort things *alphabetically*, `27` precedes `9` - 2 if before 9 (as an example).

The easiest way to get the one with the highest *numerical* value is probably to use `Sort-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem -path $path0 |Sort-Object {[int]$_.BaseName} -Descending |Select-Object -First 1
```

---

If you want to do the comparisons manually, make sure that you always pass a value that has been converted to a numerical type as the left-hand side operand:

```
$max = -1

foreach ($item in $Updates0) {
  # Get a numerical value corresponding to the basename string
  $numericalBasename = [int]$item.BaseName

  # Use this (rather than the string) for comparison + assignment
  if ($numericalBasename -gt $max) {
    $max = $numericalBasename
  }
}
```

Comment: in fact, my big error was the position of $max=0 in the loop.